# Simulink model 'to workspace' output

Tags: matlab, simulink, robotics, pid-controller

I am trying to control motor torque and am using a workspace variable in Simulink and want to output similar variable to workspace.

I have size(T_u)=[3, 91] whereas the output I am getting from the simulation has size [91, 90]

I am unable to understand why this is so.

Code that I am using:

```
load('Motor_Param.mat')

t = 1:0.1:10;
T_o = [0.05*(10-t);0.04*(10-t);0.03*(10-t)];
T_d = zeros(size(T_o));
T_e = (T_d - T_o);
C_PD = pid(100,0,10,100);
T_u = zeros(size(T_e));
for k=1:size(T_e,1)
    T_u(k,:) = lsim(C_PD,T_e(k,:),t);
%T_u(1,:)= -45.0450000000000    -44.5444552724092   -44.0439110892737   -43.5433674500493   -43.0428243541925   -42.5422818011600   -42.0417397904094   -41.5411983213986   -41.0406573935862   -40.5401170064312   -40.0395771593933   -39.5390378519326   -39.0384990835098   -38.5379608535861   -38.0374231616233   -37.5368860070837   -37.0363493894301   -36.5358133081260   -36.0352777626353   -35.5347427524223   -35.0342082769522   -34.5336743356904   -34.0331409281029   -33.5326080536564   -33.0320757118181   -32.5315439020554   -32.0310126238368   -31.5304818766308   -31.0299516599067   -30.5294219731343   -30.0288928157839   -29.5283641873264   -29.0278360872332   -28.5273085149760   -28.0267814700274   -27.5262549518604   -27.0257289599483   -26.5252034937652   -26.0246785527857   -25.5241541364848   -25.0236302443380   -24.5231068758215   -24.0225840304120   -23.5220617075865   -23.0215399068228   -22.5210186275990   -22.0204978693939   -21.5199776316868   -21.0194579139572   -20.5189387156857   -20.0184200363529   -19.5179018754402   -19.0173842324294   -18.5168671068029   -18.0163504980435   -17.5158344056347   -17.0153188290603   -16.5148037678048   -16.0142892213531   -15.5137751891906   -15.0132616708034   -14.5127486656779   -14.0122361733011   -13.5117241931606   -13.0112127247442   -12.5107017675407   -12.0101913210389   -11.5096813847285   -11.0091719580996   -10.5086630406426   -10.0081546318487   -9.50764673120954   -9.00713933821711   -8.50663245236405   -8.00612607314350   -7.50562020004906   -7.00511483257487   -6.50460997021554   -6.00410561246623   -5.50360175882257   -5.00309840878072   -4.50259556183731   -4.00209321748951   -3.50159137523496   -3.00109003457184   -2.50058919499879   -2.00008885601498   -1.49958901712007   -0.999089677814209  -0.498590837598075  0.00190750402718064

    a = sim('Motor_Control','SimulationMode','normal');
    out = a.get('T_l')
end
```

Link to .mat and .slx files is: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kGeA4Cmt8mEeM3ku_C4NtXclVlHsssuw

Comment: Hi @Capri as I don't have the Control System Toolbox installed, could you provide the arrays `C_PI`, `T_u` and `T_l` for `k=1`?

Comment: I have updated in the above code. C_PI and T_l are not being used and therefore, I have removed them.

Comment: I just wrote an answer. Please let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `Save format` in the `To Workspace` block to `Timeseries` the output will have the dimensions of the signal times the number of timesteps.

In your case I activated the option `Display->Signals & Ports->Signal dimensions` and the signal dimensions in your model look like this:

[image: Signal dimensions in Simulink model]

So the signal that you output to the workspace has the size `90`. Now if I print `size(out.Data)` I get

```
ans = 138  90
```

where 90 is the signal dimension and 138 is the number of timesteps in your Simulink model.

You could now use the last row of the data (which has the length 90) and add it to your array.

Comment: Thanks Axel. As 90 is not the dimension I need, I have managed a work around for it.

Answer (score 0):

I edit your code, the code has [21,3] output size. "21" is coming from (t_final*1/sample_time+1)

- In your code, time t should start from 0.
- Motor_Control.slx model has 0.1 sample time if you run the model for a 9 second, the output file has 91 samples for each signal and that's why you have [91, 90] sized output. I download from your drive link and this Simulink model has 2 sec. simulation.
- T_u is used as an input of the Simulink model, it is not constant so T_u must be time series.

The edited code is below;

```
load('Motor_Param.mat')
t = 0:0.1:10;
T_o = [0.05*(10-t);0.04*(10-t);0.03*(10-t)];
T_d = zeros(size(T_o));
T_e = (T_d - T_o);
C_PD = pid(100,0,10,100);
T_u = timeseries(zeros(size(T_e)),t);
for k=1:size(T_e,1)
    T_u.Data(k,:) = lsim(C_PD,T_e(k,:),t);
    a = sim('Motor_Control','SimulationMode','normal');
    out = a.get('T_l')
end
```

Comment: The output I get is:  1.0e+295 *

         0         0         0
   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000
    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000
    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000
    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000
    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000
    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000
    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
   -0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000
    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
......
    5.0673    4.0538    3.0404 I am not getting the in-between values